# Error with Characters.Font properties from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, fonts

I wrote some code to look at font properties of Excel cells text.
This simple test loops on each cell character. The program will fail with error 5 when reaching a character with a different font color.

```
Sub ExcelTextFontProperties()
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Debug.Print r.Value
For i = 1 To Len(r.Value)
    With r.Characters(i, 1).Font
    Debug.Print Str(i) & "-" & r.Characters(i, 1).Text & "-" & "-" & .Background & _
    "-" & .Bold & "-" & .Color & "-" & .ColorIndex & "-" & .Creator & "-" & .FontStyle & "-" & .Italic & _
    "-" & .Name & "-" & .Size & "-" & .Strikethrough & "-" & .Subscript & _
    "-" & .Superscript & "-" & .ThemeColor & "-" & .ThemeFont & "-" & .TintAndShade
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The error is the `.ThemeColor`.  `Attempting to access a theme color for an object whose color is not currently themed will result in an invalid request run-time error.` From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820778.aspx).  I assume you would get the same error if the font for one letter was not the same as the rest with the `.ThemeFont`

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `str(i)` may have been left over¹ from some previous attempt(s). I really not sure what it was originally intended to refer to.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExcelTextFontProperties()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        Debug.Print r.Value
        For i = 1 To Len(r.Value)
            With r.Characters(i, 1).Font
                Debug.Print Join(Array(.Parent.Text, _
                                       .Background, _
                                       .Bold, _
                                       .Color, _
                                       .ColorIndex, _
                                       .Creator, _
                                       .FontStyle, _
                                       .Italic, _
                                       .Name, _
                                       .Size, _
                                       .Strikethrough, _
                                       .Subscript, _
                                       .Superscript, _
                                       .ThemeColor, _
                                       .ThemeFont, _
                                       .TintAndShade), Chr(45))
            End With
        Next i
    Next r
End Sub
```

I've based the main method(s) to process through each cell in the current **Selection**. Using the [Join Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with proper indentation may make this a bit more readable.

---

¹ <sub>Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put **[Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant type. Using **Option Explicit** is widely considered 'best practice'.</sub>